# How to display alert message after inserting data into database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have create web app in MVS 3 
but failed to display alert message after data insert into database

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult QuestionBank(QuestionBank questionbank)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dbEntities.QuestionBanks.AddObject(questionbank);
                dbEntities.SaveChanges();
                //questionbank.SendEnquiryEmail(questionbank);
                ViewData["Message"] = "Data inserted";
                return RedirectToAction("QuestionBank");

            }
            return View(questionbank);
        }
```

Used ViewData["Message"] = "Data inserted"; which is not displayed message :(
whats going wrong or i placed it somewhere else?
OR ELSE I MAY HAVE THIS CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //i'm using jquery ready event which will call the javascript chunk after the page has completed loading
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //assuming that your variable name from the code behind is bInsertSuccess
        var bSuccess = "<%= myvar %>";
        if (bSuccess) {
            alert("Successfully Inserted");
        }
    });
</script>
```

but i dont know where i declare that variable `myvar` which checks insertion plz help

Comment: how do you use ViewData in your view?

Comment: I don't think you understand what ViewData really does. ViewData is just a "storage" for key/value pairs that can be used to "transport" data between controller and view. So somewhere in your view, you should be calling ViewData["Message"]. If you want an alert message, you will actually have to code one.

Comment: This code looks a bit weird btw: `public ActionResult QuestionBank(QuestionBank questionbank) 
{ 
  if (ModelState.IsValid) 
  { 
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("QuestionBank"); //loop back?
  }
  ...
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your .chsthml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var msg = '@ViewBag.Message';

        alert(msg);
    });
</script>
```

in your action:

```
ViewBag.Message = "1";
```

**Edit:** Apply conditional check in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var msg = '@ViewData["Message"]';
        if(msg=='1')
        alert("you are done with your thing");
    });
</script>
```

In view:

```
ViewData["Message"] = "1";
```

`ViewData["Message"]` would result in same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to user

```
TempData
```

instead of

```
ViewData
```